# How to resize a child UIView proportionally to parent resizing?

Tags: ios, uiview, resize, zooming

I am trying to create an avatar, which is a human figure clothed with various pieces of clothing.

In other words, I have a UIView which contains several UIViews. I have a zoom function where the frame of the parent doubles in size.

How do I get all the child views to resize with the parent, i.e. to double in size and stay in the right position also?

I tried using this:

```
piece.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

But that made every child completely fill to the size of the parent when I zoomed, instead of proportionately increasing in size (some are quite a bit smaller than the parent).

Comment: did you try to implement the layoutSubViews method in your parent view ?.

Comment: No, I ended up using self.transform to change the scale (which works for all subviews) and changed self.center to translate the frame (which of course shifts the whole thing including subviews). I think this is more of a hack than a solution, so I'd still like to see how to properly resize subviews when the parent's frame changes.

Comment: Try NSLayoutConstraint: relationship between two objects of the UI that must be satisfied by the constraint-based layout system so its allows developer to specify constraints on size and position of view elements.